# How to Send a Text message and Image through Whatsapp from Grails application

Tags: grails, whatsapp

I want to Send a Text message or Image or any documents through Whatsapp using my grails application. 
Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you will have to use an API for that like the "WhatsApp Business API" or something like "Twilio API for WhatsApp".

You can send API calls from your Grails application to them. I don't think there is another solution.

For Twilio, [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/quickstart) is Java example code.